# Magento 2 add downloable product programatically

Tags: magento-2.1

I know how to add a simple product but cannot create a downloadable product programmatically. I am using following code for adding downloable product information:-

```
$product->setProductHasWeight(0); // weight of product
    $product->setIsDownloadable(1);

    $doanloadable_data = array(
                    'link' =>array('title' => 'first downloable product',
                       'price' => 9,
                       'number_of_downloads' => 10,
                       'is_shareable' => 1,
                       'type' => 'url',
                       'link_url' => 'http://w3solver.com',
                       'sample' => array('url'=>'http://w3solver.com',
                                        'type' => 'url'),
                       'is_unlimited' => 0,
                    ),
                    'sample' => array('title' => 'sample',
                        'sample_url' => 'http://w3solver.com',
                        'type' => 'url',
                        )
                    );
    $product->setDownloadable($doanloadable_data);


    $product->save();
```

Anyone here can please help me to find out what is the issue over here or what I can do make it work.

Answer (score 2):

Finally I found it and explained it on this [post](http://www.w3solver.com/magento-2-create-a-downloadable-product-programmatically/)(In case it might help someone in future)

To create a downloadable product we need to set productHasWeight as zero and typeId as downloadable, once our product is created we have to provide information of link and sample as shown in below code:-

```
    $link_repository = $objectManager->create('Magento\Downloadable\Api\LinkRepositoryInterface');
    $link_interface = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Downloadable\Api\Data\LinkInterface');
    $link_interface->setTitle('first downloable product');
    $link_interface->setPrice(9);
    $link_interface->setNumberOFDownloads(10);
    $link_interface->setIsShareable(1);
    $link_interface->setLinkType('url');
    $link_interface->setLinkUrl('http://www.w3solver.com/download/qrcode.zip');
    $link_interface->setSampleType('url');
    $link_interface->setSampleUrl('http://w3solver.com');
    $link_interface->setIsUnlimited(0);
    $link_interface->setSortOrder(0);
    $link_repository->save('sku', $link_interface);

    $sample_repository = $objectManager->create('Magento\Downloadable\Api\SampleRepositoryInterface');
    $sample_interface = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Downloadable\Api\Data\SampleInterface');
    $sample_interface->setTitle('first downloable product');
    $sample_interface->setSampleType('url');
    $sample_interface->setSampleUrl('http://www.w3solver.com/download/qrcode.zip');
    $sample_interface->setSortOrder(0);

    $sample_repository->save('sku', $sample_interface);
```